# Executing system command in scala not working

Tags: scala

I want to put a line of text in a file, in bash I would do:

```
echo "a,b,c" > /home/myname/file.txt
```

Now in Scala, I tried:

```
import sys.process._
import scala.language.postfixOps
"""echo "a,b,c" > /home/myname/file.txt""" !!
```

But the line is not present in the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirecting, [ProcessBuilder](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.scala#L1) provides `#>` method.

```
import java.io.File
import sys.process._
import scala.language.postfixOps

"echo \"a,b,c\"" #> new File("/home/myname/file.txt") !!
```